# Set The Progress Bar Over 100% C#

Tags: c#, oop, progress-bar

its my first time using a *ProgressBar* in c#.
The idea is to use the *ProgressBar* as an health bar in a simple game.
The thing is I think the bar's maximum value is 100% but i would like to give it a higher value like let's say 1000% or, not sure if it's possible, give the bar an integer value instead of a percentage.

```
    progressBar1.Increment(100);
```

This is where I initialize the health to 100points. Even if I use this syntax:

```
    progressBar1.Increment(1000);
```

And I subtract :

```
    progressBar1.Increment(-25);
```

The player is loosing 1/4 of is life as if he only had 100 Health Points.
Any idea how I could change the maximum Bar value?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows Forms sorry forgot the info

Comment: Use the ProgressBar.Maximum property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have another variable that holds the player's health.  Storing the health data just in the control would not be a good idea.

You could do the following:

```
progressBar1.Value = Math.min(100, actualHealth);
```

You then update the variable `actualHealth`, which could be over the maximum control range of 100.  You could then change the control's style or another visual element to show the player is "buffed".

Comment: Ok i really like this idea but i'm kind of new with that language so how attach the current health that is going to be the updated health variable to the Progress of the bar?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk:  You would first set the `actualHealth` variable (eg: `actualHealth -= 25`), then update the progress bar (`progressBar1.Value = Math.min(100, actualHealth);`).

Comment: Ok it's the math class.min method I'm not really used too but now that you pointed that method i'm going to go read the doc for more info.
Thanks a lot Tim

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said whether you're using Windows Forms, WPF or something else, but most progress bars allow you to specify a maximum and minimum value. It sounds like it's not that you want 1000 *percent*, just a maximum value of 1000.

See [`ProgressBar.Maximum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.maximum.aspx) for a Windows Forms example.

**However**, I wouldn't personally use a `ProgressBar` for this in the first place. It *isn't* progress as such - if you just want a control that draws a bar, then find or write one. If users see what looks like a *progress* bar but which is actually just a *monitoring* bar indicating the current health etc, they'll understandably get confused.

(As Tim noted, I also wouldn't use a control as the source of truth about the state of the player. I probably wouldn't put the *display* code in the same class as the player "model" code either, but that's a separate matter.)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot i'm using windows form but if I set the property to a maximum value of 1000 and I .Increment(-25) is the -25 an integer value or 25% of 1000?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk:  It's 25 less than the current value (not 25% less).

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: No - it changes the *absolute value*, not the percentage.  As ever, I suggest you read the docs for ProgressBar.Increment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.increment.aspx - nothing in there talks about percentages.

Comment: Ok now that i think about it I don't know where I got that "percentage" idea.. but thanks Tim and Jon for the help

Answer (score 2):

Just set the progress bar's max to whatever you want.  Either in the properties window, or from code.

```
progressBar1.maximum = 7331;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for example:

```
progressBar1.Maximum = 700;
```

And when you do this:

```
progressBar1.Increment(-25);
```

you are going to do this

> 700-25

But if you like to subtract 25% you can do simply this;

```
int a = 700;

prograssBar1.Maximum = a;

//When you'd like to subtract the 25% insert this:
progressBar1.Increment(-a/(100/25));
```

Answer (score 1):

Its too late for answer but maybe this answer can be useful for someone. This code is for unknown maximum values. I mean this can help you when you don't know how much is values.

```
int percent = (int)(Convert.ToDouble(MaximumValue) > 0 ? (100 - (float)(Convert.ToDouble(Value) / Convert.ToDouble(MaximumValue)) * 100d) : 100);
```

This code is for some operation like dragging many files to a listbox object or etc...

I hope this would be useful and helpful for you. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to allow health to be greater than 100% when a player gets some sort of power boost but that this bonus health does not show up in the health bar which just runs from 0 to 100%.

Don't use the progress bar position property as the source data for the player's health. It is limited to the range of the progress bar and so simply is not suitable to the task.

Instead, use a distinct variable to maintain the player's health. This value can go above 100 but when you update the progress bar position, you clip it into range of the progress bar.

The most important message, and this is **really** important, is that you need to get out of the habit of using visual controls to store state. Store the state in a model object and update the view based on the state in the model.

Answer (score 0):

You could still go with the min - max percentage value of the progress bar while maintaining your own values outside of it.

Then you could translate the additions / subtrations to percentage values.

Answer (score 0):

You should first set:

```
progressBar1.Maximum = 1000;
progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
```

Then you may wanna set a step, or manually define its value:

```
1) progressBar1.Step = 500;
2) progressBar1.Value = 500;
```

If you go for 1) you should call .PerformStep()

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.PerformStep();
}
```